# Mysql syntax error in php query not showing up in browser

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say that I have an error in a php/mysql query :

```
$query = "SELECT * ROM users WHERE _id = :user_id";
```

Here, FROM is missing an "F".
When I launch this php file in localhost, my browser is not reacting, it should display something like that:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
```

But it doesn't, only blank page...
How do I enable this option?

EDIT: I'm using PDO.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: error_reporting is off make it on in your php.ini file

Comment: you need to invoke the mysql_error() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you use `mysql_*` functions you have to do something like: `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`
- If you use `mysqli_*`: `mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());`
- If you use `PDO`: `$stmt->execute() or die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo)); //$stmt is instance of PDOStatemen`

If you still use `mysql_*` I strongly recommend to stop using (sql injection I mean).

Comment: I edited my question, you're right about that I should have told that I'm using PDO ;) I'm trying your solution and let you know.

Comment: @BaptisteCosta Yes, PDO is quite good for usage and many of us use but not everybody, so nothing's wrong with giving full info that will be useful for other readers too. :)

Answer (score 1):

- First use mysql_error() function in your code in case if query is not executed 
  successfully. something like this :

  ```
  if(!mysql_query($query)){
     echo mysql_error();
  }
  ```
- Secondly, check in your php.ini whether error_reporting is on or off.

Then check on the browser for the error.

Comment: In my php.ini : error_reporting = E_ALL also ; error_reporting ; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE ;Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT ; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED. I'm not sure about the good one... Should I also put mysql_query($query) in every request I'm doing?